# Cannot resolve symbol HttpUrlConnection. Why?

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I want to get an HTML response by instantiating a HttpUrlConnection object.

I already imported java.net.HttpURLConnection.

This is my code:

```
HttpUrlConnection connection1 = (HttpURLConnection) form.openConnection();
```

In Android Studio HttpUrlConnection is marked in red and reads:

```
"Cannot resolve symbol 'HttpUrlConnection'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is case-sensitive. `HttpUrlConnection` is not the same as `HttpURLConnection`. Use `HttpURLConnection`.